# How to align aChartEngine Chart properly in an Android layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, achartengine

I am trying to write a code to plot a graph using aChartengine in an Android layout.I am successfully plot the graph but i am facing issue to align the Graph in the layout within a certain ViewGroup.

**MyCode :**

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

List<double[]> xValues;
List<double[]> yValues;
List<double[]> yValues1;

GraphicalView view;
MultipleTemperatureChart multiple;
RelativeLayout rlt;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    xValues = new ArrayList<double[]>();
    yValues = new ArrayList<double[]>();
    yValues1 = new ArrayList<double[]>();

    rlt = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlt);

    multiple = new MultipleTemperatureChart(this);

    int[] data = {143,144,145,137,156,146,158,139,144,143};

    double[] doubTime = new double[data.length];
    double[] doubNote = new double[data.length];
    double[] doubZero = new double[data.length];

    for(int i=0;i<data.length;i++){

        doubTime[i] = index;
        doubNote[i] = data[i];
        doubZero[i] = 0;

        index++;
    }

    xValues.add(doubTime);
    yValues.add(doubNote);
    yValues1.add(doubZero);     


    view =   multiple.execute(getApplicationContext(),xValues,yValues,yValues1);
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
    view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 400));

    rlt.addView(view);

}


}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <RelativeLayout 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="500dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="#33cc00"
                android:id="@+id/rltParams">

            <RelativeLayout 
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:id="@+id/rlt"/>

             <View 
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/rlt"
                    android:background="#cc4455"
                    android:id="@+id/view"/>

     </RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

So these are the codes and screenshots of my issue. I want to plot the graph within the **Green RelativeLayout** and also the **Red View** need to come below the graph layout.

Please suggest me some solution or technique to plot the graphs in the layout properly.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to put the chart inside the green layout try this:

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


 <RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="500dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#33cc00"
    android:id="@+id/rltParams">

  <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/rlt"/>

 <View 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"                    
        android:background="#cc4455"
        android:id="@+id/view"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Just remove the following line:

```
android:layout_below="@+id/rlt"
```

what is this Red View?

---

Try something like this:
(To see the Red View you need to put a height inside the layout @+id/rlt).

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="500dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/rltParams">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#33cc00"
        android:id="@+id/rlt"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#cc4455"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rlt"
        android:id="@+id/view"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks , red view means View layout has color code "#cc4455" , which is red in colors , sorry i didn't explain it properly

Comment: No , the total layout now Red , so , the View layout covers entire the screen